# Kotlin Unit Test - always pass

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, android-viewmodel

I have a ViewModel that has some functions for getting data from server or Local Database.

I have written an Unit Test for that ViewModel with Fake Repository.

But with or without calling repository's function my Unit Test is passed.

I tried some solutions, but none of them works.

I changed my ViewModel and my Fake Reository.

But nothing changes.

This is my ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AllGamesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getGame: GetAllGamesUseCase,
    private val getGamesByGenre: GetGamesByGenreUseCase,
    private val getAllGamesFromLocalUseCase: GetAllGamesFromLocalUseCase,
    private val connectivityObserver: ConnectivityObserver
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _state = mutableStateOf(AllGamesState())
    val state: State<AllGamesState> = _state



    private val _eventFlow = MutableSharedFlow<UIEvent>()
    val eventFlow = _eventFlow.asSharedFlow()

    private val _status = MutableStateFlow(Status.Unavailable)
    val status: StateFlow<Status> get() = _status

    init {
        networkConnectionCheck()
    }

    private fun networkConnectionCheck() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            connectivityObserver.observe().collect{ newStatus ->
                _status.value = newStatus
                if(_status.value == Status.Available){
                    getAllGames()
                }else{
                    getAllGamesFromLocal()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun getAllGames() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getGame().collect { result ->
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    handleResult(result)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun getAllGamesFromLocal(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getAllGamesFromLocalUseCase().collect{ result ->
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    handleResult(result)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun getTaggedGames(genre: String) {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            getGamesByGenre(genre).collect { result ->
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    handleResult(result)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleResult(result:Resource<List<Game>>){
        when (result) {
            is Resource.Success ->{
                _state.value = _state.value.copy(
                    allGames = result.data ?: emptyList(),
                    isLoading = false
                )
            }
            is Resource.Error ->{
                _state.value = _state.value.copy(
                    allGames = result.data ?: emptyList(),
                    isLoading = false,
                )
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    _eventFlow.emit(
                        UIEvent.ShowSnackBar(
                            result.message!!
                        )
                    )
                }

            }
            is Resource.Loading ->{
                _state.value = _state.value.copy(
                    allGames = result.data ?: emptyList(),
                    isLoading = true,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use Fake Repository for testing ViewModel like this:

```
class FakeGameRepository:GameRepository{
    private var games = mutableListOf<Game>()
    override fun getAllGames(): Flow<Resource<List<Game>>> {
        return flow { emit(Resource.Success(games)) }
    }

    override fun getGameById(id: Int): Flow<Resource<Game>> {
        val game = games.find { it.id == id }
        return flow { emit(Resource.Success(game)) }
    }

    override fun getGameByGenre(genre: String): Flow<Resource<List<Game>>> {
        val taggedGames = mutableListOf<Game>()
        games.forEach { game ->
            if(game.genre == genre){
                taggedGames.add(game)
            }
        }
        return flow { emit(Resource.Success(taggedGames)) }
    }

    override fun getAllGamesFromLocal(): Flow<Resource<List<Game>>> {
        return flow { emit(Resource.Success(games)) }
    }

    fun insertGame(insertedGames:List<Game>){
        games.addAll(insertedGames)
    }

}
```

This is the ViewModel Test:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class AllGamesViewModelTest{

    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    private lateinit var connectivityObserver: FakeNetworkConnectivityObserver
    private lateinit var viewModel: AllGamesViewModel
    private lateinit var getAllGamesUseCase: GetAllGamesUseCase
    private lateinit var getAllGamesFromLocalUseCase: GetAllGamesFromLocalUseCase
    private lateinit var getGamesByGenreUseCase: GetGamesByGenreUseCase
    private lateinit var repository: FakeGameRepository
    private lateinit var game: Game
    val games = mutableListOf<Game>()
    @Before
    fun setup(){

        repository = FakeGameRepository()
        connectivityObserver = FakeNetworkConnectivityObserver()
        getAllGamesUseCase = GetAllGamesUseCase(repository)
        getAllGamesFromLocalUseCase = GetAllGamesFromLocalUseCase(repository)
        getGamesByGenreUseCase = GetGamesByGenreUseCase(repository)
        viewModel = AllGamesViewModel(
            getAllGamesUseCase,
            getGamesByGenreUseCase,
            getAllGamesFromLocalUseCase,
            connectivityObserver
        )

        for(i in 0..10){
            game = Game(
                developer = "developer $i",
                freeToGameProfileUrl = "freeUrl $i",
                gameUrl = "gameUrl $i",
                genre = "genre $i",
                id = i,
                platform = "plat $i",
                publisher = "publish $i",
                releaseDate = "release $i",
                shortDescription = "short $i",
                thumbnail = "thumb $i",
                title = "title $i"
            )
            games.add(game)
        }
        repository.insertGame(games)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Test getAllGames when Network is Available`() = runTest {
        connectivityObserver.setStatus(Status.Available)
        repository.getAllGames()
        delay(500L)
        assertThat(viewModel.status.value).isEqualTo(Status.Available)
        assertThat(viewModel.state.value.allGames).containsExactlyElementsIn(games)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Test getAllGamesFromLocal when Network is Unavailable`() = runTest {
        connectivityObserver.setStatus(Status.Unavailable)
        repository.getAllGamesFromLocal()
        delay(500L)
        assertThat(viewModel.status.value).isEqualTo(Status.Unavailable)
        assertThat(viewModel.state.value.allGames).containsExactlyElementsIn(games)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is FakeRepository.

Because I didn't check the Status of internet, the function in FakeRepository passes the data to ViewModel.

So I change FakeRepository like this:

```
class FakeGameRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val connectivityObserver: FakeNetworkConnectivityObserver
):GameRepository{
    private var games = mutableListOf<Game>()

    override fun getAllGames(): Flow<Resource<List<Game>>> {

        return flow {
            connectivityObserver.observe().collect{status ->
                when(status){
                    Status.Available ->{
                        emit(Resource.Success(games))
                    }
                    else ->{
                        games = emptyList<Game>().toMutableList()
                        emit(Resource.Error("No Internet Connection"))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //...

}
```

So in Test classes for the variable that its type is FakeRepository, I passed connectivityObserver like this:

```
repository = FakeGameRepository(connectivityObserver)
```